# Python numpy groupby multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

Is there a way to make a group by aggregation by multiple columns in numpy?
Im trying to do it with this module: https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies
Goal is to get a faster groupby than pandas.
for example:

```
group_idx = np.array([
np.array([4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 7, 8, 7, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1]),
np.array([4, 3, 2, 4, 7, 1, 4, 1, 7, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1, 14 1]),
np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1])
]
a = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1])

result = aggregate(group_idx, a, func='sum')
```

It should be like pandas df.groupby(['column1','column2','column3']).sum().reset_index()

Comment: Are they all positive numbers in `group_idx`?

Comment: yes, there are only positive values in group_idx.

Comment: Are you OK with adding a dependency on [`numba`](https://numba.pydata.org/)?

Comment: Sure, I think thats possible.

Comment: Can you show us the exact output format? Are you looking for 2D array output with index and a summations?

Comment: Yes 2D. In pandas: df.groupby(['column1','column2','column3']).sum().reset_index()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `group_idx` has positive values, we can use a dimensionality-reduction based method. We are assuming the first three columns as the groupby ones and the last (fourth) one as the data column to be summed.

**Approach #1**

We will stick to NumPy tools and also bring in `pandas.factorize` in the mix.

```
group_idx = df.iloc[:,:3].values
a = df.iloc[:,-1].values

s = group_idx.max(0)+1
lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(group_idx.T,s)

sidx, unq_lidx = pd.factorize(lidx)
pp = np.empty(len(unq_lidx), dtype=int)
pp[sidx] = np.arange(len(sidx))
k1 = group_idx[pp]

a_sums = np.bincount(sidx,a)
out = np.hstack((k1, a_sums.astype(int)[:,None]))
```

**Approach #2**

Bringing in numba and sorting -

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def step_sum(a_s, step_mask, out, group_idx_s):
    N = len(a_s)
    count_iter = 0
    for j in nb.prange(3):
        out[count_iter,j] = group_idx_s[0,j] 
    out[count_iter,3] = a_s[0]
    for i in nb.prange(1,N):
        if step_mask[i-1]:
            out[count_iter,3] += a_s[i]
        else:
            count_iter += 1
            for j in nb.prange(3):
                out[count_iter,j] = group_idx_s[i,j] 
            out[count_iter,3] = a_s[i]
    return out

group_idx = df.iloc[:,:3].values
a = df.iloc[:,-1].values

s = group_idx.max(0)+1
lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(group_idx.T,s)

sidx = lidx.argsort()
lsidx = lidx[sidx]
group_idx_s = group_idx[sidx]
a_s = a[sidx]

step_mask = lsidx[:-1] == lsidx[1:]    
N = len(lsidx)-step_mask.sum()
out = np.zeros((N, 4), dtype=int)
out = step_sum(a_s, step_mask, out, group_idx_s)
```

---

**Comparison checks**

For doing the comparison check, we can use something like :

```
# get pandas o/p and lexsort
p = df.groupby(['agg_a','agg_b','agg_c'])['to_sum'].sum().reset_index().values
p = p[np.lexsort(p[:,:3].T)]

# Output from our approaches here, say `out`. Let's lexsort
out = out[np.lexsort(out[:,:3].T)]

print(np.allclose(out, p))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. It looks good, but if we are handling bigger arrays, np.bincount runs into memory problems, because it wants to allocate too much memory. On speed test, its much faster with 199 µs and 5.85 ms for pandas.

Comment: @ChristianFrei Check out just added `Tweak #1`? So, skip the last three steps from App#1 and use the tweak steps instead.

Comment: Thanks I have tested it. On small datasets its working well. But on a bigger one I get a shape missmatch on np.vstack:
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 2357420 and the array at index 1 has size 2355491

The difference is only 2071...

Comment: @ChristianFrei Can you edit `np.bincount(sidx,a)` to `np.bincount(sidx,a, minlength=unq_groups.shape[1])` and try?

Comment: Yes the size fits now. I have compared the output from your code with pandas.groupby. I see that there is a missmatch in column sum.
Maybe I can attache a example df to this question

Comment: @ChristianFrei Does the order of rows matter? The output from this solution should be the same as with pandas but with different order.

Comment: order doesn't matter. On bigger df's I receive a different sum size as in pandas groupby. For small df's its correct.

Comment: @ChristianFrei Yeah can you post the dataframe used in a reproducible manner?

Comment: Here is a df: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gustiii/testdf/main/testdf.csv
If I group by 'agg_a','agg_b','agg_c' and sum by 'to_sum'. I got on some groups different sums.

Comment: Thats brilliant!

Comment: There is a small Issue on the last line of approach 2. You have to remove "lsidx" from the arguments, because its not part of step_sum func.